# iptables masquerade traffic from ip range to specific interface

Tags: iptables, docker, masquerade

I have an environment where I have multiple network interfaces: `eth0` and `vpn1`.
I am running docker which has an iptables masquerade rule to masquerade traffic from `172.17.0.0/16`: `-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.0/16 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE`

The rule currently allows traffic from `172.17.0.0/16` to reach the open internet via `eth0`.

The current setup looks like this (with the VPN enabled):

```
$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fd01:db8:1111::3/128 scope global 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fd01:db8:1111::2/128 scope global 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 60:45:bd:84:92:d9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.1.0.76/16 metric 100 brd 10.1.255.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::6245:bdff:fe84:92d9/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:51:89:34:f2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: vpn1: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1280 qdisc mq state UNKNOWN group default qlen 500
    link/none 
    inet 172.16.0.2/32 scope global vpn1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 2606:4700:110:8276:300:469c:7cb9:760a/128 scope global 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::427:bcd6:837f:e0e1/64 scope link stable-privacy 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

```
$ ip -br link
lo               UNKNOWN        00:00:00:00:00:00 <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> 
eth0             UP             60:45:bd:84:92:d9 <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> 
docker0          DOWN           02:42:51:89:34:f2 <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> 
vpn1   UNKNOWN        <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP>
```

```
$ ip -4 -br addr
lo               UNKNOWN        127.0.0.1/8 
eth0             UP             10.1.0.76/16 metric 100 
docker0          DOWN           172.17.0.1/16 
vpn1   UNKNOWN        172.16.0.2/32
```

```
$ ip route
default via 10.1.0.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp src 10.1.0.76 metric 100 
10.1.0.0/16 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.1.0.76 metric 100 
10.1.0.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp scope link src 10.1.0.76 metric 100 
168.63.129.16 via 10.1.0.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp src 10.1.0.76 metric 100 
169.254.169.254 via 10.1.0.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp src 10.1.0.76 metric 100 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown
```

```
$ ip rule
0:      from all lookup local
32765:  not from all fwmark 0x100cf lookup 65743
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
```

```
$ nft list ruleset
table ip security {
    chain OUTPUT {
        type filter hook output priority 150; policy accept;
        meta l4proto tcp ip daddr 168.63.129.16 tcp dport 53 counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
        meta l4proto tcp ip daddr 168.63.129.16 skuid 0 counter packets 463 bytes 198542 accept
        meta l4proto tcp ip daddr 168.63.129.16 ct state invalid,new counter packets 0 bytes 0 drop
    }
}
table ip nat {
    chain DOCKER {
        iifname "docker0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 return
    }

    chain POSTROUTING {
        type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat; policy accept;
        oifname != "docker0" ip saddr 172.17.0.0/16 counter packets 0 bytes 0 masquerade 
    }

    chain PREROUTING {
        type nat hook prerouting priority dstnat; policy accept;
        fib daddr type local counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump DOCKER
    }

    chain OUTPUT {
        type nat hook output priority -100; policy accept;
        ip daddr != 127.0.0.0/8 fib daddr type local counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump DOCKER
    }
}
table ip filter {
    chain DOCKER {
    }

    chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 {
        iifname "docker0" oifname != "docker0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
        counter packets 0 bytes 0 return
    }

    chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 {
        oifname "docker0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 drop
        counter packets 0 bytes 0 return
    }

    chain FORWARD {
        type filter hook forward priority filter; policy drop;
        counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump DOCKER-USER
        counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
        oifname "docker0" ct state related,established counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
        oifname "docker0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump DOCKER
        iifname "docker0" oifname != "docker0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
        iifname "docker0" oifname "docker0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
    }

    chain DOCKER-USER {
        counter packets 0 bytes 0 return
    }

    chain OUTPUT {
        type filter hook output priority filter; policy accept;
        ip daddr 5.34.183.68 counter packets 0 bytes 0 drop
        ip daddr 95.181.164.182 counter packets 0 bytes 0 drop
    }
}
table inet vpn {
    chain input {
        type filter hook input priority filter; policy drop;
        iif "lo" accept
        iif "vpn1" accept
        meta nfproto ipv4 udp sport 67 udp dport 68 accept
        ip6 saddr fe80::/10 ip6 daddr fe80::/10 udp sport 547 udp dport 546 accept
        meta l4proto ipv6-icmp accept
        ip protocol icmp accept
        ip saddr 162.159.137.105 tcp sport 443 accept
        ip saddr 162.159.138.105 tcp sport 443 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7::a29f:8969 tcp sport 443 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7::a29f:8a69 tcp sport 443 accept
        ip saddr 162.159.193.2 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:100::a29f:c102 accept
        ip saddr 162.159.36.1 accept
        ip saddr 192.0.0.0/2 accept
        ip saddr 32.0.0.0/3 accept
        ip saddr 64.0.0.0/3 accept
        ip saddr 128.0.0.0/3 accept
        ip saddr 16.0.0.0/4 accept
        ip saddr 112.0.0.0/4 accept
        ip saddr 176.0.0.0/4 accept
        ip saddr 0.0.0.0/5 accept
        ip saddr 104.0.0.0/5 accept
        ip saddr 168.0.0.0/5 accept
        ip saddr 12.0.0.0/6 accept
        ip saddr 96.0.0.0/6 accept
        ip saddr 164.0.0.0/6 accept
        ip saddr 8.0.0.0/7 accept
        ip saddr 102.0.0.0/7 accept
        ip saddr 160.0.0.0/7 accept
        ip saddr 11.0.0.0/8 accept
        ip saddr 101.0.0.0/8 accept
        ip saddr 163.0.0.0/8 accept
        ip saddr 100.128.0.0/9 accept
        ip saddr 162.0.0.0/9 accept
        ip saddr 100.0.0.0/10 accept
        ip saddr 162.192.0.0/10 accept
        ip saddr 162.160.0.0/11 accept
        ip saddr 162.128.0.0/12 accept
        ip saddr 162.144.0.0/13 accept
        ip saddr 162.152.0.0/14 accept
        ip saddr 162.156.0.0/15 accept
        ip saddr 162.159.36.1 accept
        ip saddr 162.159.193.2 accept
        ip6 saddr 8000::/1 accept
        ip6 saddr 4000::/2 accept
        ip6 saddr ::/3 accept
        ip6 saddr 3000::/4 accept
        ip6 saddr 2800::/5 accept
        ip6 saddr 2000::/6 accept
        ip6 saddr 2400::/7 accept
        ip6 saddr 2700::/8 accept
        ip6 saddr 2680::/9 accept
        ip6 saddr 2640::/10 accept
        ip6 saddr 2620::/11 accept
        ip6 saddr 2610::/12 accept
        ip6 saddr 2608::/13 accept
        ip6 saddr 2600::/14 accept
        ip6 saddr 2604::/15 accept
        ip6 saddr 2607::/16 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:8000::/17 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606::/18 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:6000::/19 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:5000::/20 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4800::/21 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4000::/22 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4400::/23 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4600::/24 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4780::/25 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4740::/26 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4720::/27 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4710::/28 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4708::/29 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4704::/30 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4702::/31 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4701::/32 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:8000::/33 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:4000::/34 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:2000::/35 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:1000::/36 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:800::/37 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:400::/38 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:200::/39 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:100::/40 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:80::/41 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:40::/42 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:20::/43 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:10::/44 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:8::/45 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700::/46 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:4::/47 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:6::/48 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7:8000::/49 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7:4000::/50 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7:2000::/51 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7:1000::/52 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7:800::/53 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7:400::/54 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7:200::/55 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7:100::/56 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7:80::/57 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7:40::/58 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7:20::/59 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7:10::/60 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7:8::/61 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7:4::/62 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7:2::/63 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7:1::/64 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7:0:8000::/65 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7:0:4000::/66 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7:0:2000::/67 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7:0:1000::/68 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7:0:800::/69 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7:0:400::/70 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7:0:200::/71 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7:0:100::/72 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7:0:80::/73 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7:0:40::/74 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7:0:20::/75 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7:0:10::/76 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7:0:8::/77 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7:0:4::/78 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7:0:2::/79 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7:0:1::/80 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7::8000:0:0/81 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7::4000:0:0/82 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7::2000:0:0/83 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7::1000:0:0/84 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7::800:0:0/85 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7::400:0:0/86 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7::200:0:0/87 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7::100:0:0/88 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7::80:0:0/89 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7::40:0:0/90 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7::20:0:0/91 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7::10:0:0/92 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7::8:0:0/93 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7::4:0:0/94 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7::2:0:0/95 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7::1:0:0/96 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7::/97 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7::c000:0/98 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7::8000:0/99 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7::b000:0/100 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7::a800:0/101 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7::a400:0/102 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7::a000:0/103 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7::a300:0/104 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7::a200:0/105 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7::a2c0:0/106 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7::a2a0:0/107 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7::a280:0/108 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7::a290:0/109 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7::a298:0/110 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7::a29c:0/111 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7::a29e:0/112 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7::a29f:0/113 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7::a29f:c000/114 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7::a29f:a000/115 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7::a29f:9000/116 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7::a29f:8000/117 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7::a29f:8c00/118 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7::a29f:8800/120 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7::a29f:8b00/120 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7::a29f:8980/121 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7::a29f:8a80/121 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7::a29f:8900/122 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7::a29f:8a00/122 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7::a29f:8960/123 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7::a29f:8a60/123 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7::a29f:8950/124 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7::a29f:8a50/124 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7::a29f:8948/125 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7::a29f:8a48/125 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7::a29f:8944/126 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7::a29f:8a44/126 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7::a29f:8942/127 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7::a29f:8a42/127 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7::a29f:8940 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:7::a29f:8a40 accept
    }

    chain output {
        type filter hook output priority filter; policy drop;
        oif "lo" accept
        oif "vpn1" goto tun
        ip saddr 0.0.0.0 ip daddr 255.255.255.255 udp sport 68 udp dport 67 accept
        ip6 saddr fe80::/10 ip6 daddr ff02::1:2 udp sport 546 udp dport 547 accept
        ip6 saddr fe80::/10 ip6 daddr ff05::1:3 udp sport 546 udp dport 547 accept
        meta l4proto ipv6-icmp accept
        ip daddr 162.159.137.105 tcp dport 443 accept
        ip daddr 162.159.138.105 tcp dport 443 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7::a29f:8969 tcp dport 443 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7::a29f:8a69 tcp dport 443 accept
        ip daddr 162.159.193.2 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:100::a29f:c102 accept
        ip daddr 162.159.36.1 accept
        ip daddr 192.0.0.0/2 accept
        ip daddr 32.0.0.0/3 accept
        ip daddr 64.0.0.0/3 accept
        ip daddr 128.0.0.0/3 accept
        ip daddr 16.0.0.0/4 accept
        ip daddr 112.0.0.0/4 accept
        ip daddr 176.0.0.0/4 accept
        ip daddr 0.0.0.0/5 accept
        ip daddr 104.0.0.0/5 accept
        ip daddr 168.0.0.0/5 accept
        ip daddr 12.0.0.0/6 accept
        ip daddr 96.0.0.0/6 accept
        ip daddr 164.0.0.0/6 accept
        ip daddr 8.0.0.0/7 accept
        ip daddr 102.0.0.0/7 accept
        ip daddr 160.0.0.0/7 accept
        ip daddr 11.0.0.0/8 accept
        ip daddr 101.0.0.0/8 accept
        ip daddr 163.0.0.0/8 accept
        ip daddr 100.128.0.0/9 accept
        ip daddr 162.0.0.0/9 accept
        ip daddr 100.0.0.0/10 accept
        ip daddr 162.192.0.0/10 accept
        ip daddr 162.160.0.0/11 accept
        ip daddr 162.128.0.0/12 accept
        ip daddr 162.144.0.0/13 accept
        ip daddr 162.152.0.0/14 accept
        ip daddr 162.156.0.0/15 accept
        ip daddr 162.159.36.1 accept
        ip daddr 162.159.193.2 accept
        ip6 daddr 8000::/1 accept
        ip6 daddr 4000::/2 accept
        ip6 daddr ::/3 accept
        ip6 daddr 3000::/4 accept
        ip6 daddr 2800::/5 accept
        ip6 daddr 2000::/6 accept
        ip6 daddr 2400::/7 accept
        ip6 daddr 2700::/8 accept
        ip6 daddr 2680::/9 accept
        ip6 daddr 2640::/10 accept
        ip6 daddr 2620::/11 accept
        ip6 daddr 2610::/12 accept
        ip6 daddr 2608::/13 accept
        ip6 daddr 2600::/14 accept
        ip6 daddr 2604::/15 accept
        ip6 daddr 2607::/16 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:8000::/17 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606::/18 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:6000::/19 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:5000::/20 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4800::/21 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4000::/22 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4400::/23 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4600::/24 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4780::/25 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4740::/26 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4720::/27 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4710::/28 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4708::/29 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4704::/30 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4702::/31 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4701::/32 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:8000::/33 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:4000::/34 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:2000::/35 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:1000::/36 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:800::/37 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:400::/38 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:200::/39 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:100::/40 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:80::/41 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:40::/42 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:20::/43 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:10::/44 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:8::/45 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700::/46 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:4::/47 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:6::/48 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7:8000::/49 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7:4000::/50 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7:2000::/51 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7:1000::/52 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7:800::/53 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7:400::/54 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7:200::/55 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7:100::/56 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7:80::/57 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7:40::/58 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7:20::/59 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7:10::/60 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7:8::/61 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7:4::/62 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7:2::/63 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7:1::/64 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7:0:8000::/65 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7:0:4000::/66 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7:0:2000::/67 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7:0:1000::/68 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7:0:800::/69 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7:0:400::/70 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7:0:200::/71 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7:0:100::/72 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7:0:80::/73 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7:0:40::/74 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7:0:20::/75 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7:0:10::/76 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7:0:8::/77 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7:0:4::/78 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7:0:2::/79 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7:0:1::/80 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7::8000:0:0/81 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7::4000:0:0/82 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7::2000:0:0/83 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7::1000:0:0/84 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7::800:0:0/85 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7::400:0:0/86 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7::200:0:0/87 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7::100:0:0/88 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7::80:0:0/89 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7::40:0:0/90 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7::20:0:0/91 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7::10:0:0/92 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7::8:0:0/93 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7::4:0:0/94 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7::2:0:0/95 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7::1:0:0/96 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7::/97 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7::c000:0/98 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7::8000:0/99 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7::b000:0/100 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7::a800:0/101 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7::a400:0/102 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7::a000:0/103 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7::a300:0/104 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7::a200:0/105 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7::a2c0:0/106 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7::a2a0:0/107 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7::a280:0/108 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7::a290:0/109 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7::a298:0/110 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7::a29c:0/111 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7::a29e:0/112 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7::a29f:0/113 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7::a29f:c000/114 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7::a29f:a000/115 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7::a29f:9000/116 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7::a29f:8000/117 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7::a29f:8c00/118 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7::a29f:8800/120 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7::a29f:8b00/120 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7::a29f:8980/121 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7::a29f:8a80/121 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7::a29f:8900/122 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7::a29f:8a00/122 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7::a29f:8960/123 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7::a29f:8a60/123 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7::a29f:8950/124 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7::a29f:8a50/124 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7::a29f:8948/125 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7::a29f:8a48/125 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7::a29f:8944/126 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7::a29f:8a44/126 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7::a29f:8942/127 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7::a29f:8a42/127 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7::a29f:8940 accept
        ip6 daddr 2606:4700:7::a29f:8a40 accept
    }

    chain tun {
        ip saddr 172.16.0.2 accept
        ip6 saddr 2606:4700:110:8ac1:21f5:87c2:8c2e:882a accept
        ip6 saddr fe80::/10 accept
        ip protocol tcp reject with tcp reset
        reject
    }
}
```

How do I set up the masquerade rule so that traffic from `172.17.0.0/16` reaches the open internet via `vpn1`?

Comment: Questions seeking installation, configuration or diagnostic help must include the desired end state, the specific problem or error, sufficient information about the configuration and environment to reproduce it, and attempted solutions. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers and are unlikely to get good answers. read step by step my words

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, I've added the output of the current interfaces and routes on the machine to my question.

Comment: Sorry, it looks like your VPN does a lot of settings including using nftables, but none for forwarding. I don't know what VPN it is. I'm not sure I can address this question myself, but in any case, you should 1/ state what VPN it is and a web link to the tool configuring it, 2/ add `ip route show table 65743`.

Comment: Ah I guess from the edit it's CloudFlare WARP. So I won't have access to it. I think you should search in its documentation how to change its behavior for doing routing/forwarding rather than trying to fix what it's currently doing that doesn't appear to involve the routing/forwarding case.